# Creating a Drop-Up Menu

Tags: html, css

Currently the bottom-right menu on my website moves up when you click a menu item:  http://www.jameswinfield.co.uk/v2.html

How do I get the menu itself to stay where it is and the menu items to display upwards?

My CSS is below:

```
.menu4 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.menu4 nav {
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -ms-opacity: 0;
  -o-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu4 input#slide4:checked ~ nav {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  -ms-opacity: 1;
  -o-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu4 label {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.menu4 input#slide4 {
  display: none;
}

.menu4 input#slide4:checked ~ label.open i {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.menu4 label i,
.menu4 nav,
.menu4 nav ul li a span {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu4 label,
.menu4 nav ul li a i,
.menu4 nav ul li a span {
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.menu4 nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu4 nav ul li a i {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.menu4 nav ul li a span {
  font-family: 'Lato', tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17.14285714px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 0;
}

.menu4 nav ul li a:hover span {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.menu4 nav ul li.active a span {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.menu4.top {
  bottom: 0px;
}

.menu4.bottom {
  bottom: 0px;
}

.menu4.left,
.menu4.left label {
  right: 0;
}

.menu4.right,
.menu4.right label {
  right: 0;
}

.menu4.horizontal nav ul li,
.menu4.horizontal nav ul li a span {
  float: left;
}

.menu4.left.horizontal nav {
  margin-right: -50px;
}

.menu4.left.horizontal input#slide4:checked ~ nav {
  margin-right: 120px;
}

.menu4.right.horizontal nav {
  margin-right: -60px;
}

.menu4.right.horizontal input#slide4:checked ~ nav {
  margin-right: 60px;
}


.menu4.blue label,
.menu4.blue nav ul li a ul li i {
  color: #F82D27;

}

.menu4.blue nav ul li a span {
  color: #F235E9;
}

.mixcloud {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.youtube {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could place the relevant HTML in the question as well so that what you have can be re-created easily without having to follow a link. I removed the off-topic text from the question. If you remember to research your problem, provide relevant code in the question itself and provide a simple description of what you want to achieve, you will generally have well received questions :)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.  I am slowly getting this place - it is quite intimidating when you just get downvoted without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The menu slides upwards from outside of the viewport, so `position: fixed` is a good choice here.

The menu container is also given `position: fixed` and it will remain fixed in place, relevant to the viewport.

### Example

This is using `:hover` to simplify things, but can easily be adapted.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 20px;
  padding: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
}
nav > a {
  background: #F90;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
}
.slideUp {
  bottom: -400px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #F00;
  position: fixed;
  transition: bottom .3s linear;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav:hover + .slideUp,
.slideUp:hover {
  bottom: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">I am a menu item, hover me please</a>
</nav>
<div class="slideUp"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It's half fixed it by putting bottom:0 on .menu4 label part - it already had position: fixed.

The slide-out menu still moves up when expanded but I'm kind of tempted just to keep it as it is.

Thanks for your help